# Terraform Import Resources and Looping Over Those Resources

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Terraform and looking to utilize it for management of Snowflake environment using the provider of "chanzuckerberg/snowflake". I am specifically looking to leverage it for managing an RBAC model for roles within Snowflake.

The scenario is that I have about 60 databases in Snowflake which would equate to a resource for each in Terraform. We will then create 3 roles (reader, writer, all privileges) for each database. We will expand our roles from there.

The first question is, can I leverage map or object variables to define all database names and their attributes and import them using a for_each within a single resource or do I need to create a resource for each database and then import them individually?

The second question is, what would be the best approach for creating the 3 roles per database? Is there a way to iterate over all the resources of type snowflake_database and create the 3 roles? I was imagining the use of modules, variables, and resources based on the research I have done.

Any help in understanding how this can be accomplished would be super helpful. I understand the basics of Terraform but this is a bit of a complex situation for a newbie like myself to visualize enough to implement it. Thanks all!

Update:
This is what my project looks like and the error I am receiving is below it.

variables.tf:

```
variable "databases" {
  type = list(object(
    {
      name           = string
      comment        = string
      retention_days = number
  }))
}
```

databases.auto.tfvars:

```
databases = [
  {
    name           = "TEST_DB1"
    comment        = "Testing state."
    retention_days = 90
  },
  {
    name           = "TEST_DB2"
    comment        = ""
    retention_days = 1
  }
]
```

main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.25.25"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  username = "user"
  account  = "my_account"
  region   = "my_region"
  password = "pwd"
  role     = "some_role"
}


resource "snowflake_database" "sf_database" {
  for_each = { for idx, db in var.databases: idx => db }

  name                        = each.value.name
  comment                     = each.value.comment
  data_retention_time_in_days = each.value.retention_days
}
```

To Import the resource I run:

> terraform import snowflake_database.sf_databases["TEST_DB1"]
> db_test_db1

I am left with this error:

> Error: resource address
> "snowflake_database.sf_databases["TEST_DB1"]" does not exist in the
> configuration.
>
> Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the
> root module. For example:
>
> resource "snowflake_database" "sf_databases" {   # (resource
> arguments) }

Answer (score 2):

had this exact same problem and in the end the solution was quite simple.

you just need to wrap your import statement within single brackets.

so instead of

```
terraform import snowflake_database.sf_databases["TEST_DB1"] db_test_db1
```

do

```
terraform import 'snowflake_database.sf_databases["TEST_DB1"]' db_test_db1
```

this took way to long to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the databases using for_each and referring to the actual resources with brackets in the import command. Something like:

```
terraform import snowflake_database.resource_id_using_for_each[foreachkey]
```

You could then create three `snowflake_role` and three `snowflake_database_grant` definitions using for_each over the same map of databases used for the database definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the info @restlessmodem. I have updated my post with an example of my project and the error I am facing based on my attempt to implement what you have explained. Am I missing something or could it be the provider doesn't allow this type of looping on import?